# Multiple forks, wait for the first to finish

Tags: c, fork, wait, mkfifo

I'm kind of new to all the `fork`, `exec` and `wait` functions. I have an assignment, which requires I `fork` my main process i times and then use all the children to write on to different fifos for each process. For example, if I have 3 children, I'll have to write to 3 different fifos. Then, my parent process has to wait for the first one to finish writing on any fifo, and read the data from that specific fifo. What baffled me is that my parent process has to wait for the first to finish and not for all the processes to finish. If I had to wait for all, I would use `while(wait(NULL)>0)`. However what do you do in this case? I've written a sample code below:

```
pid_t *pid;
int    i;

pid = malloc(sizeof(pid_t)*children);
for(i=0;i<children;i++)
{
     if((pid[i]=fork())<0)
     { /* error */ }

     if(pid[i]==0)
     {
          //WriteOnFifos
          return 0;
     }
     else
     {
           //wait for the first process to finish
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It won't even compile. `fork` is not a function call

Comment: oops yeah sorry I' ll edit

Comment: Don't just edit. Post the full code.

Comment: But it's kind of a theoretical question. What would you do in this case, how to wait for the first process to exit.

Comment: At least post code that compiles! See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok sorry for that. I will make sure next time, I was kind in a hurry!

Comment: Why don't you use `waitpid` with the `WNOHANG` option to loop through the `pid` list?

Comment: @DavidCullen I ran through the manual and found this : `WNOHANG     return immediately if no child has exited.`. Would you mind explaining how would this help? Maybe I'm not quite grasping what it does.

Comment: You use the `WNOHANG` option to poll the children to see if one has exited. If one has exited, `waitpid` will return a non-zero value. Then you use the `pid` to determine which FIFO to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `wait(NULL)`. As the documentation says, it will wait until one of its children terminate. So it will do what you want, i.e.: wait for the first child to finish.

Comment: In case the first process has exited,  the parent process continues, and reads from the fifo the data the first process has written, what happens if the rest of the processes haven't finished their jobs and the parent wants to read from them? Is there a way for it to wait for them as well?

Comment: That is a different question. I'm not sure I understand your question. Maybe you should read some basic theory on the topic. You can wait for a specific child with `waitpid(pid, NULL, 0)`.

Comment: "What happens if the rest of the processes haven't finished their jobs and the parent wants to read from them?". That depends how many bytes you read from the FIFO. If you read more bytes than the child has written, `read()` will normally block.

Comment: OK, I'll check if it works correctly and if it does I'm gonna upvote your answer. Thanks.